# Tiling a rectangle with $n$ rectangles to maximize product of areas

Tags: optimization, extremal-combinatorics

Consider a rectangle $R$ with integer width and integer height.

We want to tile $R$ using exactly $n$ rectangles with integer dimensions.

Now we carefully want to choose such rectangles so that $\max\ (w_1\times h_1)\times \ldots \times (w_n\times h_n)$ for every rectangle $(w_i, h_i)$.

What approaches are there to tackle this optimization problem! Thank you!

Comment: please clarify your question, write a complete sntence, what does $(w_i,h_n)$ have to do with it? Also what do you mean in your comment to @Ross answer below when you say $R=100$ do you mean $R$ is a rectangle, or $R$ is just an area (so then the rectangle might be 1x100 or 10x10)?

Comment: ok ... I don't get it anyway, it makes no sense to me as stated

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of $n$ numbers that add up to the area of $R$. To maximize their product, you would like them as equal as possible.  If the area of $R$ is divisible by $n$, make all the rectangles the same size if possible.  I don't know any other advice to give.